# How to dynamically call the parent methods from child component?

Tags: angular

Below is my code

parent component.ts

```
data  = [{
    "name":"This is my name",
    "editButton": {
                "name":"Edit",
                "click":"editMethod()",
            },
    "addButton": {
                    "Name":"Add",
                    "click":"addMethod()"
    }
}]

editMethod(rowVal){
    console.log("calling edit");
}


addMethod(rowVal){
    console.log("calling add");
}
```

parent.html

```
<button-app [childdata]="data" (opmethod)="iDotknowtoCallMethod()"></button-app>
```

childComponent.ts

```
@Input()
childdata;

@Output()
opmethod = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

child component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let ech in childdata">
    <label>{{ech.name}}</label>
    <button *ngIf="ech.editButton" (click)="ech.editButton.click" >{{ech.editButton.name}}</button>
    <button *ngIf="ech.addButton" (click)="ech.addButton.click">{{ech.addButton.name}}</button>
</div>
```

We can call the parent method using `emit`, that is not my question.

**I am trying to call the parent method, which names are provided in the `data` object.** But I am not having any Idea how to call this method.

Comment: @Justcode This is not a duplicate question. I am trying to call the dynamic parent methods.

Comment: your json must be data  = [{ "name":"This is my name", "editButton": {               "name":"Edit", "click":this.editMethod()}...  }, That's, "click" is NOT a string is a function

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks for your comment. I got the answer. :)

Comment: @Justcode Again, this is not duplicate question, I got the answer for my question.

Comment: @mkHun it says possible, and as far as I see your question seems to be duplicate.

Comment: @mkHun: Then probably don't call the function in the object, just attach the reference: like: `click: this.editMethod`

Comment: @xyz I am not calling the function. I am giving the reference only in the Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Eliseo comment, I got the answer for my question

parentcomponent.ts

```
data  = [{
    "name":"This is my name",
    "editButton": {
                "name":"Edit",
                "click":this.editMethod,
            },
    "addButton": {
                    "Name":"Add",
                    "click":this.addMethod
    }
}]
```

parentcomponent.html

```
<button-app [childdata]="data" (opmethod)="$event"></button-app>
```

childcomponent.html

```
<div *ngFor="let ech in childdata">
    <label>{{ech.name}}</label>
    <button *ngIf="ech.editButton" (click)="opmethod.emit(ech.editButton.click(ech))" >{{ech.editButton.name}}</button>
    <button *ngIf="ech.addButton" (click)="opmethod.emit(ech.addButton.click(ech))">{{ech.addButton.name}}</button>
</div>
```

I should emit the method in the child component. In the parent component I should declare only the `$event`  it is calling the dynamic methods.

Answer (score 1):

You have to emit an `Output` event from child component to parent using

`opmethod.emit('Your data')`

child.html

```
<button *ngIf="ech.editButton" (click)="opmethod.emit('Your data')" >{{ech.editButton.name}}</button>
    <button *ngIf="ech.addButton" (click)="opmethod.emit('Your data')">{{ech.addButton.name}}</button>
```

And in parent.html

```
<button-app [childdata]="data" (opmethod)="addMethod($event)"></button-app>
```

Comment: I know about the `emit`, but I am trying to call the `addMethod` and `editMethod` dynamically.

Comment: I that case also you still have to emit an event with the `method` name in data. And then the handler in parent component should call that method.

Comment: Yes correct but my doubt is how to set the handle name in the template dynamically as follow `(opmethod)="hereShouldBeDynamicMethodName($event)"` ?

Comment: @mkHun: What decides the dynamic method name?

Comment: @xyz I got the answer for my question.

Answer (score 0):

its not a good approach. change your data to this:

```
enum BottonTypes {
    edit,
    add
}
class BUttonClass {
    name: string;
    type: ButtonTypes
}
data: ButtonClass[]  = [{
        name:"This is my name",
        type: ButtonTypes.edit
    },
    {
       'name':"This is my name",
        type: ButtonTypes.save
    }
]

<div *ngFor="let ech in childdata">
    <label>{{ech.name}}</label>
    <button *ngIf="ech.type === 0" (click)="buttonClicked(ech)" >{{ech.editButton.name}}</button>
    <button *ngIf="ech.type === 1" (click)="buttonClicked(ech)">{{ech.addButton.name}}</button>
</div>
```

and in your ts:

```
opmethod = new EventEmitter<ButtonClass>();

buttonClicked(btn: ButtonClass)
{
    this.opmethod.emit(btn);
}
```

parent component html:

```
<button-app [childdata]="data" (opmethod)="iDotknowtoCallMethod($event)"></button-app>
```

parent component.ts:

```
iDotknowtoCallMethod(btn: ButtonCLass) {
    do what you want
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I got the answer for my question.